# How to handle touches in SKShapeNode subclass?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, touchesbegan, skshapenode

I'm looking for an easy way to handle touches inside an SKShapeNode Subclass. For that I tried to use `touchesBegan`, but it did not work..

```
class Shape: SKShapeNode {


convenience init(rectOfSize: CGSize, colorOfRectangle rectColor: UIColor) {

    self.init()

    self.init(rectOfSize: rectOfSize)
    self.fillColor = rectColor
    self.position = CGPointMake(rectOfSize.width, rectOfSize.height)
}
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    print("touch")   
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure `userInteractionEnabled` for the shape object is set to `true`. It is `false` by default